# What are some good free, open sourced, cross platform game engines?

Tags: c++, game-engine

I have a great idea for a 3D game, but I do not want to start from scratch with OpenGL. I also do not want to reinvent the wheel. I found OGRE, and it seemed like it was perfect for my needs, except it lacked physics and audio. I do not need crazy graphics, shaders or high polygon counts, but the world will be very big, so it needs good scene or LOD management. I also will probably want to bring in rigged characters so skeletal biped animation support would be needed. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: how important is c++ in this?  there are game engines based on a programming language called lua which seem to be all the rage in open source games.

Comment: Why not use Ogre + a separate physics library? As far as I can see, Ogre does have a few libraries for sound.

Comment: Looks like this belongs on Gamedev http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at some of the answers from [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21/easy-to-use-cross-platform-3d-engines-for-c-game-development). You may find some useful libraries listed.

If you're open to alternatives to C++, you can check out [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/109/what-c-libraries-can-be-used-to-support-game-development/226#226) answer on the game development stack exchange website. The answer covers lots of options for game engines, physics engines and Graphics/Sound engines. Most listed here focus on C# (because of the question obviously), but some of them are wrappers for C++ libraries (you can always check out the native libraries that are being wrapped).

Answer (score 1):

Old versions of the Quake engine are released under the GPL.